# Converting Dummy symbols to Symbols in Sympy

Tags: sympy

How can I convert Dummy variables (sympy.core.symbol.Dummy) to regular symbols in Sympy?

For example, say we want to find all vectors (x_1,x_2) in the kernel of a matrix that satisfying some equation f(x_1,x_2) = 0.

I would break it into two steps. First:

```
from sympy import Matrix

M = Matrix( [[1,0],
             [0,0] ])
zeros = Matrix([[0],
                [0]])
sol = M.gauss_jordan_solve(zeros)[0]
```

Second: solve f(sol) = 0.

But I don't know how to tell Sympy to treat the entries of sol as symbols. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sol.free_symbols` returns a set of all symbols in `sol` ("free" is a detail that does not matter on this occasion). If you'd like to replace them with some other symbols of your choice, then create new symbols (as many as needed) and replace using `subs`, as shown below.

```
from sympy import symbols
dummies = list(sol.free_symbols)
my_syms = symbols("x0:{}".format(len(dummies)))   # Example: symbols("x0:3") creates x0, x1, x2
sol = sol.subs(dict(zip(dummies, my_syms)))
```